# Where do I put setTimeout in jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, settimeout

This code runs on page load but I want to delay it. I've tried adding setTimeout to this jQuery code but as soon as I do the code doesn't run at all. Can anyone help me put it in the right place?

```
(function ($) {
        $.fn.countTo = function (options) {

            // merge the default plugin settings with the custom options
            options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});

            // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
            var loops = Math.ceil(options.speed / options.refreshInterval),
                increment = (options.to - options.from) / loops;

            return $(this).each(function () {
                var _this = this,
                    loopCount = 0,
                    value = options.from,
                    interval = setInterval(updateTimer, options.refreshInterval);

                function updateTimer() {
                    value += increment;
                    loopCount++;
                    $(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals));

                    if (typeof (options.onUpdate) == 'function') {
                        options.onUpdate.call(_this, value);
                    }

                    if (loopCount >= loops) {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        value = options.to;

                        if (typeof (options.onComplete) == 'function') {
                            options.onComplete.call(_this, value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        };

        $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
            from: 0,  // the number the element should start at
            to: 100,  // the number the element should end at
            speed: 1000,  // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
            refreshInterval: 100,  // how often the element should be updated
            decimals: 0,  // the number of decimal places to show
            onUpdate: null,  // callback method for every time the element is updated,
            onComplete: null,  // callback method for when the element finishes updating
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it after the call of your function and before execute the main code. Main code will be executed after declared time in `setTimeout`

Try:

```
(function ($) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.fn.countTo = function (options) {

                // merge the default plugin settings with the custom options
                options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});

                // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
                var loops = Math.ceil(options.speed / options.refreshInterval),
                    increment = (options.to - options.from) / loops;

                return $(this).each(function () {
                    var _this = this,
                        loopCount = 0,
                        value = options.from,
                        interval = setInterval(updateTimer, options.refreshInterval);

                    function updateTimer() {
                        value += increment;
                        loopCount++;
                        $(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals));

                        if (typeof (options.onUpdate) == 'function') {
                            options.onUpdate.call(_this, value);
                        }

                        if (loopCount >= loops) {
                            clearInterval(interval);
                            value = options.to;

                            if (typeof (options.onComplete) == 'function') {
                                options.onComplete.call(_this, value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            };

            $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
                from: 0,  // the number the element should start at
                to: 100,  // the number the element should end at
                speed: 1000,  // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
                refreshInterval: 100,  // how often the element should be updated
                decimals: 0,  // the number of decimal places to show
                onUpdate: null,  // callback method for every time the element is updated,
                onComplete: null,  // callback method for when the element finishes updating
            };



        jQuery(function ($) {
            $('.timer').countTo({
                from: 500,
                to: 1000,
                speed: 2000,
                refreshInterval: 50,
                onComplete: function (value) {
                    console.debug(this);
                }
            });
        });
            },3000);
 })(jQuery);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KYEDg/2/)

Comment: I've tried this code and it just won't fire. Can't imagine what I'm doing wrong since I just copied what you wrote.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @vsdev Look and the a simple example in demo